# Elisp: Copy buffer to clipboard

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

Made an effort with Elisp, but didn't work - says incorrect number of arguments. If you know Elips, probably this could be done elegantly with zero effort. But I include my heavy-handed stuff so you immediately will understand what I'm trying to do.

```
(defun copy-all ()
    "Copy entire buffer to clipboard"
    (interactive)
    (let ((pos (point)))
        (progn
            (mark-whole-buffer)
            (clipboard-kill-ring-save)
            (keyboard-quit)
            (goto-char pos)
            (message "Copy done."))))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of saving the point and restoring it later, use `save-excursion`.  It's more robust and will restore the buffer as well.  There's no need for an explicit `progn` either.

That said, in this case simply pass the ranges to `clipboard-kill-ring-save` instead of trying to mess around with the region.  For example:

```
(defun copy-all ()
    "Copy entire buffer to clipboard"
    (interactive)
    (clipboard-kill-ring-save (point-min) (point-max)))
```

Remember, elisp help is always available inside emacs with `describe-function` (<kbd>C-h f</kbd>) if you're unsure about what arguments a function requires.

Answer (score 6):

You're making it tougher than you have to.

```
(defun copy-whole-buffer ()
  "Copy entire buffer to clipboard"
  (interactive)
  (clipboard-kill-ring-save (point-min) (point-max)))
```